# vagrant ssh を行ったときに homesteadのアスキーアートが何故か出なくなった

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

### 問題の要約

laravelの環境構築を vagrant + virtualbox で行いました．

今までは vagrant ssh を行うと「Thanks for using homestead」というAAが表示されていましたが，突然表示されなくなりました．

代わりに，下記のようなログが出ます．

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-100-generic x86_64)

Last login: Mon Jul 18 23:53:45 2022 from 10.0.2.2
```

AAが表示されなくなっただけで，sshに入った後のコマンドは問題なく実行できるようですが，なぜAAが表示されないのか気になっています．

### 考えたこと

エラーがあまりに出るので vagrant destroy して vagrant up することを何度か繰り返しました．

その最中に突然AAが出なくなったので，vagrant の再起動のやりすぎでは？と思っています．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そのメッセージはmotdによるものです。
具体的な理由は環境構築やその後の作業で何をしたか書かれていないので分かりませんが、laravelの設定がされない手順でセットアップしたかUbuntuのパッケージ更新などで、固有設定ではなくUbuntuのデフォルト設定になってるのではないでしょうか。
https://github.com/laravel/settler/blob/master/scripts/amd64.sh#L711